# Is the given database relation in 3NF or 2NF?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

Given below is a database relation R, and it's set of FD:

[image]

From the set of FDs, it is clear that the candidate keys are **AB** and **BC** .

With these candidate keys, I think the dependencies **A -> C** and **C -> A** represent partial dependencies (as A can be determined with just C and not BC; similar argument for C and AB)

Therefore, in my opinion this relation is in 1NF (2NF conditions are not fulfilled) .

However, as per the evaluation done by my prof for this question, this relation is in 3NF, because for every dependency given, the left side is either a superkey (AB,AC) or the right side is part of a candidate key (C,A). I agree that these criteria for 3NF are being met, but aside these criteria, the first criterion is that R should be in 2NF (which it clearly is not..)

Comment: Yes, your professor is correct. It's in 3NF but not in BCNF.

Comment: Why do you say it's not in 2NF?

Comment: Stated that in the question.. I think the FDs A-->C and C-->A are partial dependencies which 2NF doesn't allow.

Comment: 2NF doesn't allow that when the right part is a non-prime attribute. Both right parts here (A, C) are prime attributes.

Comment: Okay..I thought it applies for any partial dependency! Thanks @ypercube

Answer (score 1):

In this example,

> AB and BC are candidate keys.

and

> D is a non-prime attribute
>
> Since,there is no partial dependency on non-prime attribute

and

> The non-prime attribute is dependent only on super key

The relation is in **3NF** but it is not in **BCNF**
as the all left hand side are not **super key**

Hope,this helps!